# Which is best or good book or tutorial to understand linux file or directory structure

Tags: linux

I have been using Linux for a while. But i could not understood what does the folder

```
/var

/etc
```

actually means

Why sometimes the same file is at many places like

```
/bin/sh

/sbin/sh
```

and other basics especially the structure of directories. Why they are used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a much better description of the filesystem.  http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html

Answer (score 3):

In every Linux distribution you'll have a `man hier` man page that describes the filesystem hierarchy :)

In short, `/etc` is for configurations & admin scripts (those that initialize your system). `/var` is for variable content in common. `/bin` is used for common system applications, `/sbin` are those apps that usually require root (superuser-bin). Also there's `/usr/bin` for binaries installed by the user.

Cheers!  :)

Comment: +1 for very short & useful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Mirror51, [this page](http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-directory-structure-overview.html) gives a good overview.

Each linux distro has some subtle difference from the others, but for the most part, they all adhere to roughly the same file structure.

Comment: That link is a bit off in some of it's descriptions. I read it and thought /sys and /dev were incorrect and the comments at the bottom of the article seem to echo my concerns.  Which is really odd b/c it's a debian admin document.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to accumulate rep for these type of answers, but you *may* just want to try googling for these before asking - this link was the third result after googleing for "linux filesystem structure".

Comment: It also doesn't mention /proc

Comment: Yah, you're right, there has to be a better explanation out there than that...